# Do... while statement

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

I understand why CODE A returns a sequence of numbers (that's the loop process), but why is CODE B returning a summation?

```js
// CODE A:
let counter = '';
let i = 1;

do {
  counter = counter + i;
  i++;
} while (i < 15);
console.log(counter);
//1234567891011121314
```

```js
// CODE B:
let counter = 4;
let i = 1;

do {
  counter = counter + i;
  i++;
} while (i < 15);
console.log(counter);
//109
```

Comment: Because on the first example `counter` is a string an on the second it's an integer

Comment: I suspect you have not went through a tutorial on the fundamentals of javascript. Knowing the basic data types is critical. I suggest you go through a tutorial on the fundamentals before diving directly into coding.

Comment: Oh! my bad. Thank you guys. @OmarAbdelBari, this I have been doing for the past one week plus, something times, our eyes seems to overlook things. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

in *code A* you are using counter as a string and the variable *i* is been added at the end of the string that means you will get a output of **12345..** in **string** whereas, in *code B* you are using counter as a integer so you are adding a integer in a integer so the correct code will be.

```
// CODE A:
let counter = "";
let i = 1;

do {
  counter = counter + i;
  i++;
} while (i < 15);
console.log(counter);
// 1234567891011121314

// CODE B:
let counter = "4";
let i = 1;

do {
  counter = counter + i;
  i++;
} while (i < 15);
console.log(counter);
// 41234567891011121314
```

Answer (score 0):

In Code A you initialized your counter variable with a string and when you use + operator with strings in javascript it concats them.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

In Code B you initialized your counter variable with the number and in the case of numbers, the + operator will add instead of concatenating.

You need to study the basics of data types in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In code A you initialized one of your variable(counter) as a character variable. If you add a character with an integer, in that case the result will act as a character variable. You can see an example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_oper_concat5).

On code B you declared both variables as integer. So, they are behaving like integer variables does. In this case they are summing their values.

These are root javascript knowledge but very useful in many way.